# What is the objective of the data collection process?

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining

My main question is in data mining and machine learning area. What is the objective of the data collection process?

any help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data collection is the process of gathering and measuring information on variables of interest, in an established systematic fashion that enables one to answer stated research questions, test hypotheses, and evaluate outcomes.

Answer (score 0):

Data collection itself is usually *not* considered to be part of data mining itself. It is assumed the data is already there (the mountain), and you need to find the gold nuggets in there.